# When does $|f(x)-L| = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

In the definition of limit we say as we hone in on $x=a$ then $f(x)$ hones in on $L$ on the vertical axis.

While the difference between $x$ and $a$ must be nonzero it says nothing of the sort for $f(x)$ and $L$ on the other axis, just that the distance must be less than epsilon.

So in general when does  $|f(x)-L| = 0$? Does it only occur in certain situations? Because if we can actually equal $L$ and yet continue to get closer to $L$ by bringing $x$ even closer to $a$ then what does that even mean since we've already "arrived"?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @JorgeFernández Last paragraph

Comment: Basically the usual explanation of epsilon Delta definition of limit is that we keep getting closer and closer to $a$ and $L$ without actually reaching $a$, but the definition allows for $f(x)=L$ to be possible which doesn't make sense to me, since we can continue honing in on $a$

Comment: I wouldnt say that we can get closer and closer, I would say that we can get as close as we want to $L$ by getting sufficiently close to $a$.

Comment: But then the definition allows you to equal $L$ exactly, not merely approaching it forever, despite $x$ never reaching $a$

Comment: the definition in no point says that you can approach $L$ more and more. It just says that you can approach $L$ as good as you want by taking $x$ sufficiently close. It doesnt say that the approximation has to increase strictly. You seem to be putting extra meaning to the definition, when this meaning just isnt true or relevant to the use of the theory.

Comment: @JorgeFernández I'm going by the interpretation that you see almost everywhere online. You can approach L as good as you want but getting it to equal L exactly without actually reaching $a$ is really unusual and not mentioned anywhere

Comment: its not at all unusual, have you heard of constant functions?

Comment: or consider the function $x\sin(1/x)$ around $0$.

Comment: Then maybe next time you could put that in an answer rather than throw around baseless, condescending insults.

Comment: maybe next time you can appreciate when people try to answer you questions.

Comment: That does not justify your (now-deleted) insulting comment. You owe me an apology.

Comment: Ok fine, Im sorry, have a good day. Please dont answer this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no answer "in general", but it generally can occur... It won't in the special case where $f$ is strictly monotonous near $a$.

For exemple with $f(x)=L$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, you will have allways $| f(x)- L|=0$ ; or with $a=0$, $L=0$ and $f(x)=x\sin(\frac1x)$, you will have, near $a$ a infinity of $x$ such that $|f(x)-L|=0$.

Comment: So constant functions or repetitive curvy functions like sin? Or things that aren't monotone around $a$?

Comment: @JorgeFernández Flagged, absolutely uncalled for

Comment: @user525966: yes, things that aren't strictly monotone around $a$.

Comment: @user525966: just to be clear : when it is strictly monotonous around $a$, it is sure that it won't happen. But when it is not you can't know for sure : for exemple with $f(x)=x(2+\sin(1/x))$, $a=0$ and $L=0$, you will have $f(x)-L\neq 0$ for all $x\neq 0$ either (since $f(x)<0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)>0$ if $x>0$).